# ActionListener in different class

Tags: java, actionlistener

I have button and label in different panels of different classes.How can I use ActionListener of the button to set random value in the label?

Comment: Please show the code you have done so far

Comment: E.g.  Use a getter for label in the other class and set the value of label it in this class.